# Asp.Net MVC Bundle Minification not working in release

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am getting a MapRequestHandler error when requesting a minified asset in release. Who is supposed to handle this request in release?  Debug rendering works fine and delivers the right files.

### my bundling map:

```
Key: "~/Plugins/Pingo.Demo.BootstrapPrimary.1.0.0.3/Content/css"
item(s): "~/Plugins/Pingo.Demo.BootstrapPrimary.1.0.0.3/Content/bootstrap.css"
     ,"~/Plugins/Pingo.Demo.BootstrapPrimary.1.0.0.3/Content/site.css"
```

### Debug rendered:

```
<link href="/Plugins/Pingo.Demo.BootstrapPrimary.1.0.0.3/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Plugins/Pingo.Demo.BootstrapPrimary.1.0.0.3/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

### Release rendered:

```
<link href="/plugins/Pingo.Demo.BootstrapPrimary.1.0.0.3/Content/css?v=DPgH9yYiO33UIbEOm8f4duzFsUqfKWua2il4TOVUrtQ1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The release version results in a MapRequestHandler 404 where ASP.Net is thinking this is a staticFile.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you .NET Reflector for decompiling System.Web.Optimization.

System.Web.Optimization has a PreStartInitMethod, which only got called if System.Web.Optimization was referenced by my main application.  In my case, I had my own PreStartInitMethod.  In my version, I was calling  BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(assembly) on a bunch of plugin assemblies.  System.Web.Optimization was one of those assemblies.  The PreStartInitMethod in System.Web.Optimization was not known early enough(via a direct reference), hence it was never called.

I had to find all PreStartInitMethods of all assemblies I loaded, and then call those methods from my PreStartInitMethod().

An eyeopening moment for me was that there was a lot of assemblies that I was not aware had PreStartInitMethods, so this is really a plugin 101 lesson when dealing with .NET.